# Fortran Syntax error in OPEN statement

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I couldn't figure out what's wrong with the following Fortran OPEN statement:

```
filename = 'state_save.txt'                
OPEN(FILE=TRIM(dir)//TRIM(filename),UNIT=ffunit,STATUS='old',FORM='formatted',
IOSTAT=ios, readonly)
```

[I added CR for clarity]

Compiled under gfortran (from gcc-4.8.1), the above gives the following error:

```
(dir)//TRIM(filename),UNIT=ffunit,STATUS='old',FORM='formatted',IOSTAT=ios, rea
                                                                           1
Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)
```

The code might compile OK with `ifort` (but I don't have ifort).

Can someone please explain what went wrong and how to write the statement in a standard compliant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `READONLY` keyword for `OPEN()` is not part of the Fortran standard. Although nearly all commerical compilers support it, it does not appear to be supported by gfortran. But nowadays, you can use `action='read'` to get the same result, which is supported by the language standard (and also seems to work for me).

Comment: In theory, gFortran is supposed to be able to support such extension via the "-fdec" etc switches, but there are "issues", some of which are discussed here  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245989/standard-fortran-shared-option-in-open-statement/43959175#43959175)