# SHARED option in OPEN Statement in the Fortran standard

Tags: gcc, file-io, fortran, standards, gfortran

In this documentation [HP Fortran doc](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0476.htm), the OPEN statement accept SHARED and READONLY options.
In this documentation [Standard Fortran 2008 doc](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf), the OPEN statement dosn't accept SHARED or READONLY options.
Since I'm using **gfortran**  comes with **gcc 4.4.7** to compile a Fortran source file on Linux,I used a ruse to get around half the problem. I used

```
 OPEN(...,ACTION=READ,...)  instead of READONLY.
```

But can't find an other ruse (:)) to replace SHARED Option. (Like **Something=Shared**).
Anyone have a ruse to get arround that?

Comment: Suggestion: If the file opened by OPEN statement is shared by default, I can remove this option.

Comment: Sharing with what? Shared in which sense?

Comment: In sense that other users / programs can access the file. please look here:  http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04621387.  Section 6.9.3 Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you need it to be shared for? It's probably easier for you to work around using it, rather than trying to hack in a non-standard keyword.

Comment: This is some VMS specifics. Are you using gfortran on OpenVMS? If not, don't care about it. Unix and Windows use different ways of acces control.

Comment: Ross: I'm going to hack anythings, gfortran doesn't know the SHARED option and stop compiling, normal this options is not in the standard. if the source file is compiled with HP Fortran which is not standard it will work

Comment: Vladimir -> I have gfortran on Linux and I'm compiling a fortran source which writes for VMS in the past. So, i will remove this option as you say

Answer (score 0):

Those IO extensions (SHARED, READONLY, etc) as well as other extensions, as would be available with DEC based Fortran should be available in GCC/gFortran via the "-fdec" and related compiler switches.

However, I found some confusion in the online GCC docs.  Apparently, some older versions of gFortran (and in particular g77) may require the compiler to have been built with the libf2c element, and there may be differences on Unix (c.f. Win etc).

It is not clear exactly which versions of gFortran accept this.  For example, under Windows, with GCC/gFortran 6.x, it would not recognise the "-fdec" switch.

Apparently, GCC/gFortran v7.x have all that working, but v7 is still in "development mode" ... are you feeling lucky :-) ?

Also, some references give dire warnings about reliance on "extensions".

Here are some pages of interest:

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran/News

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Extended-I_002fO-specifiers.html

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Option-Summary.html

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-Dialect-Options.html

The last link seems particularly "dire" on the subject.